# Unable to install any ruby version through rvm on a Mac M1 Silicon Chip

Tags: rubygems, apple-m1, apple-silicon

Example of Error response:

```
TTRAN-YK0WK9W9PM:virtual_terminal tuantran$ rvm install 2.7.6
ruby-2.7.6 - #removing src/ruby-2.7.6..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/12.3/arm64/ruby-2.7.6.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/tuantran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.7.6 - #downloading ruby-2.7.6, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.7.6 - #extracting ruby-2.7.6 to /Users/tuantran/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.6.....
ruby-2.7.6 - #configuring.........................................................................
ruby-2.7.6 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.7.6 - #compiling......................................................
Error running '__rvm_make -j10',
please read /Users/tuantran/.rvm/log/1658248808_ruby-2.7.6/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Solution: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5153

1. Right click Terminal from the Application/Utilities folder, Get Info, tick the "Open using Rosetta" box.
2. Uninstall Homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/*
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

3. Reinstall Homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

4. Restart terminal
5. Check Homebrew is working fine: `brew doctor`
6. Reinstall openssl: `brew install openssl`
7. Install Ruby: `rvm install 2.7` Or any version

Comment: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5153#issuecomment-1301062739
Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

**The following worked for me -**

You can check the path of ssl directory in your system with the command given below.

```
brew --prefix openssl@3
```

[image]

After that run with the below command with SSL directory path

rvm reinstall 3.3.0 --with-openssl-dir=`your ssl directory path`

```
rvm reinstall 3.3.0 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and got me past the OpenSSL error.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me - https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5153#issuecomment-1301062739

```
brew install libffi
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include" rvm install 2.5.1
```

Answer (score -4):

A simple uninstall and install of brew and rvm did the trick for me.

- uninstall rvm
- uninstall brew
- make sure that in none of your dotfiles openssl libs are added to your path
- update to the latest xcode command line tools
- install brew
- do **not** manually install openssl
- install rvm
- instal any ruby version you like

please do not install brew or start the terminal with rosetta, this will slow down massively more or less everything.

edit: it looks like this works only for ruby versions >= 2.7.2
ruby versions prior to 2.7.2 will have the same issue.